# Syntax coloring within diffs?

Tags: emacs, diff, syntax-highlighting

In emacs, when I diff code I lose the syntax highlighting. With my theme anyway all text is light gray. Added lines do have a green background, and removed lines do have a red background, etc. But the code keywords, etc are not colored like they are when I'm using that language's mode. Is there a way to turn on ruby syntax highlighting in diffs?

As an example of a tool that does this - if you look at diffs on github the code syntax highlighting is there, as well as highlighting for added/removed lines.

Comment: The underlying problem is that syntax highlighting needs a whole program to work. I see two solutions: 1) Open the original file, syntax highlight it, and copy back the syntax highlighting to the diff buffer. (This is similar to what org-mode do to highlight blocks). 2) Create a new simplified highlighter that knows about keywords and other trivial things. (I guess this corresponds to how other tools to this.)

Answer (score 0):

Syntax coloring in diffs is enabled by default in Emacs 27.

Comment: I'm using 27.2 and it is not.